# How do I pass objects along from my Main class to other classes

Tags: java

I'm learning to code java and I encountered some problems in which I could use help understanding how things work.

I've made a list containing "Images", on my Main class, called "myList".

```
public class Main{

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<Images> myList = new ArrayList<Images>();
  ...
```

And I want to access it on this "System" class. But it doesn't seem to let me.
The plan is to access a position (the 3rd, in this example) on the given list (list.get(2)).
So I created the method "work".

```
//Example    
public class System{
public static boolean work(List<Images> list){
    if( list.get(2).equals(Something) )
        return false;
    else ... return true;
}
```

On this same System class I'm trying to use the method "work", giving it the List that I created on my Main class (myList).

```
public class System{
...
if( work(myList) ) //Don't know how to reffer to myList
 return something;
```

Gives me the error "myList cannot be resolved to a variable".
So the problem is how to reffer to the list I made on my Main, named "myList".

Not sure if I explained that too well but any suggestions?

Comment: How are `Main` and `System` related? Does one call a method of the other? How?

Comment: At some point you must be instatiating `System` from inside main, so you can call `work(myList)`. If you want to then use that list elsewhere in `System`, then you COULD save it locally as an instance variable in `System`. The issue is that `myList` is encapsulated in class `Main`, and is therefore (in your case) scoped as `package protected`. You could make it public, but that is very bad practise.

Comment: Why have a class with the same name as something in the `java.lang` package (`System`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a List a property of System class, then pass it in the constructor

```
public class System {
    private List<Images> images;

    public System(List<Images> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    //your other methods
}
```

Ah, in your main you should also pass the list:

```
System system = new System(myList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option its to make myList **public static** and access it like this:

```
Main.myList
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare one helper class and declare your list with setter and getters. Mainatin a singleton object of this class and use that list then in different other classes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure its accessible.

Right now your list is scoped the main() function. which is static to boot.

You need to make it accessible. You can do this by storing it in a static variable and having a static function return it.
Or you pass the main object along to other object, so they can access it.

```
public class Main {
    private List<Images> myList = new ArrayList<Images>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Main(args);
    }

    public Main(String[] args) {
       myList.add('foo.png');
       myList.add('bar.png');
       System mySystem = new System(this);
    }

    public List<Images> getImages() {
        return myList();
    }

}

public class System{
    Main global;
    public System(Main main) {
        global = main;
    }
    public void doSomething() {
       Iterator<Images> it = global.getImages().iterator();
       while(it.hasNext()) {
          Images images = it.next();
       }
    }
}
```